# Looping two variables and testing every 1000ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have two variables:

```
var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe');
var time = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().text();
var newTime = setInterval(function() {
  var newT = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().text();
 },500);
```

As you can see one variable is in a setInterval and the other is not. So technically when I test these in a conditional it has to be inside the interval. Does anyone know how I can get these so that it will update the first variable if the second variable changes and then loop again? EX:

```
Var Time =  [12:30:39 23/05/13]

Var newT =  [12:31:39 23/05/13]
```

So now

```
Var Time =  [12:31:39 23/05/13]
```

So then we would now need to test the var NewT again. Hope this explained it a little better. I am going to keep trying different things though if you have a suggestion please post it. Thanks guys

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. All your callback does is create a local variable, which is immediately discarded.

Comment: Before I console.log everything. Then send a new message. So the first var was different. Then the newT was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could misunderstood your problem, but use:

```
var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe');
var time = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().text();
var newTime = setInterval(function() {
  var newT = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().text();
  if(newT != time)//seems like always true but im just speculating
     time = newT;
 },500);
```

Comment: This seems logical, then the next step would be to do whatever else I wanted in the iconditional? I'll try it out.

Comment: Why would you check `newT != time`? If `time == newT`, then assigning `time = newT` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Because if newT does not equal time, alert New Message, then change the variable time to newT the if statement then would be true in the sense. This works perfectly as all I did was add an Alert before assigning the new data to time. Thank you!

Comment: @Asad just to provide the underground logic here, if any ;)

Comment: I'll make a bin really quick

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ixagel/1/edit check that out and see what its doing as it works nicelty